# What is difference between Azure Cloud Shell Vs Bastion?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

What is difference between Azure Cloud Shell Vs Bastion ?

I am trying tuo understand use case scenario of Bastion. I can use azure cloud shell from the portal to connect / administer my azure recources (cli / powershell)

I also noticed that Bastion  provides similar service.

Is there any other use case for Bastion and in which it is superior / advantageus over cloud shell.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ; this answer is indeed useful.

Answer (score 1):

Bastion allows you to RDP or SSH into virtual machines without opening public IP ports. Cloud Shell is just a browser-based CLI running on an Azure-managed container and already logged in to Azure. You can't connect to services running on your private networks with Cloud Shell. It's just for administering your Azure resources.

Below are the references to official Azure documentation.

- [Azure Bastion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/)
- [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview)

Comment: Now you can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/private-vnet